# lead or lag function to get several values, not just the nth

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, lead

I have a tibble with a list of words for each row. I want to create a new variable from a function that searches for a keyword and, if it finds the keyword, creates a string composed of the keyword plus-and-minus 3 words.

The code below is *close*, but, rather than grabbing **all three** words before and after my keyword, it grabs the single word 3 ahead/behind.

```
df <- tibble(words = c("it", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", 
                       "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times"))
df <- df %>% mutate(chunks = ifelse(words=="times", 
                                    paste(lag(words, 3), 
                                          words, 
                                          lead(words, 3), sep = " "),
                                    NA))
```

The most intuitive solution would be if the `lag` function could do something like this: `lead(words, 1:3)` but that doesn't work.

Obviously I could pretty quickly do this by hand (`paste(lead(words,3), lead(words,2), lead(words,1),...lag(words,3)`), but I'll eventually actually want to be able to grab the keyword plus-and-minus *50* words--too much to hand-code.

Would be ideal if a solution existed in the tidyverse, but any solution would be helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be `sapply`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    chunks = ifelse(
      words == "times",
      sapply(
        1:nrow(.),
        function(x) paste(words[pmax(1, x - 3):pmin(x + 3, nrow(.))], collapse = " ")
        ),
      NA
      )
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   words chunks                      
   <chr> <chr>                       
 1 it    NA                          
 2 was   NA                          
 3 the   NA                          
 4 best  NA                          
 5 of    NA                          
 6 times the best of times it was the
 7 it    NA                          
 8 was   NA                          
 9 the   NA                          
10 worst NA                          
11 of    NA                          
12 times the worst of times
```

Although not an explicit `lead` or `lag` function, it can often serve the purpose as well.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @arg0naut but without dplyr:

```
r  = 1:nrow(df)
w  = which(df$words == "times")
wm = lapply(w, function(wi) intersect(r, seq(wi-3L, wi+3L)))

df$chunks <- NA_character_
df$chunks[w] <- tapply(df$words[unlist(wm)], rep(w, lengths(wm)), FUN = paste, collapse=" ")

# A tibble: 12 x 2
   words chunks                      
   <chr> <chr>                       
 1 it    <NA>                        
 2 was   <NA>                        
 3 the   <NA>                        
 4 best  <NA>                        
 5 of    <NA>                        
 6 times the best of times it was the
 7 it    <NA>                        
 8 was   <NA>                        
 9 the   <NA>                        
10 worst <NA>                        
11 of    <NA>                        
12 times the worst of times
```

The data.table translation:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(df)

w = DT["times", on="words", which=TRUE]
wm = lapply(w, function(wi) intersect(r, seq(wi-3L, wi+3L)))

DT[w, chunks := DT[unlist(wm), paste(words, collapse=" "), by=rep(w, lengths(wm))]$V1]
```

Answer (score 4):

`data.table::shift` accepts a vector for the `n` (lag) argument and outputs a list, so you can use that and `do.call(paste` the list elements together. However, unless you're on data.table version >= 1.12, I don't think it will let you mix negative and positive `n` values (as below).

With data table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, chunks := trimws(ifelse(words != "times", NA, do.call(paste, shift(words, 3:-3, ''))))]

#     words                       chunks
#  1:    it                         <NA>
#  2:   was                         <NA>
#  3:   the                         <NA>
#  4:  best                         <NA>
#  5:    of                         <NA>
#  6: times the best of times it was the
#  7:    it                         <NA>
#  8:   was                         <NA>
#  9:   the                         <NA>
# 10: worst                         <NA>
# 11:    of                         <NA>
# 12: times           the worst of times
```

With `dplyr` and only using data.table for the `shift` function:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(chunks = do.call(paste, data.table::shift(words, 3:-3, fill = '')),
         chunks = trimws(ifelse(words != "times", NA, chunks)))

# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#    words chunks                      
#    <chr> <chr>                       
#  1 it    NA                          
#  2 was   NA                          
#  3 the   NA                          
#  4 best  NA                          
#  5 of    NA                          
#  6 times the best of times it was the
#  7 it    NA                          
#  8 was   NA                          
#  9 the   NA                          
# 10 worst NA                          
# 11 of    NA                          
# 12 times the worst of times
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a another `tidyverse` solution using `lag` and `lead`

```
laglead_f <- function(what, range)
    setNames(paste(what, "(., ", range, ", default = '')"), paste(what, range))

df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(words), funs_(c(laglead_f("lag", 3:0), laglead_f("lead", 1:3)))) %>%
    unite(chunks, -words, sep = " ") %>%
    mutate(chunks = ifelse(words == "times", trimws(chunks), NA))
## A tibble: 12 x 2
#   words chunks
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 it    NA
# 2 was   NA
# 3 the   NA
# 4 best  NA
# 5 of    NA
# 6 times the best of times it was the
# 7 it    NA
# 8 was   NA
# 9 the   NA
#10 worst NA
#11 of    NA
#12 times the worst of times
```

The idea is to store values from the three `lag`ged and `lead`ing vectors in new columns with `mutate_at` and a named function, `unite` those columns and then filter entries based on your condition where `words == "times"`.